# Rotating Square in JavaScript (using p5 & triganometry)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have created this code

```
var points = [
[100, 100],
[100, -100],
[-100, -100],
[-100, 100]
];
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    translate(200, 200);
    fill(0);
    beginShape();
    for (var x = 0; x < points.length; x++) {
        points[x] = rotatePoint(0, 0, points[x][0], points[x][1], 1);
        vertex(points[x][0], points[x][1]);
        console.log("vertex: "+String(points[x][0])+" "+String(points[x][1]));
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
}

function getVectDist(p1X, p1Y, p2X, p2Y) {
    var deltaX = p1X-p2X;
    var deltaY= p1Y-p2Y;
    var vect=[deltaX, deltaY];
    return vect;
}

//Function to rotate a point around the origin or first point

function rotatePoint(originX, originY, pointX, pointY, angle) {
    var dist = getVectDist(originX, originY, pointX, pointY);
    //calculating the hypotenuse of dist
    var hyp = Math.sqrt((dist[0]*dist[0])+(dist[1]*dist[1]));
    console.log("hypotenuse"+String(hyp));
    //calculating coords
    var y = Math.cos(angle) * hyp;
    var x = Math.sin(angle) * hyp;
    return [x, y];
}
```

to try and create a rotating square. However, it just produces a weird projectile-like moving diagonal line that moves at 45 degrees before turning into a single pixel in the centre of the screen. Does anyone know why?
thanks.

Comment: Can you please link to a CodePen or a JSFiddle that's running your code?

Answer (score 0):

I made your code into a codepen, you can check it out here: https://codepen.io/Awesomennjawarrior/pen/yXVbJZ?editors=0010 
I used p5 vectors, you may want to check the [p5 reference](http://p5js.org/reference/) if you don't know what they are. The codepen is fully functional, with minor changes to your code. Also, in case you didn't already know, there is a `rotate` function in p5 that could have produced the same results with much less trouble. ;)